# Access to path denied when using c#

Tags: asp.net, virtualbox

I am trying to read the content of a text file, my code works fine when path added manually however when using a variable I get denied.
I have added sharing on the folder and the text file with the following user or group names all with full control.

Everyone
IUSR
SYSTEM
Administrator(servername\Administrator)
Administrators(servername\Administrators)
Users(servername\Users)
IIS_IUSRS(servername\IIS_IUSRS)
TrustedInstaller

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.Odbc;
    using System.Text;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connectionString = "RishtonConnect";
        string queryString = "SELECT * FROM [AllSite] ;";
        OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand(queryString);
        using (OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection("DSN=Rishton"))
        {
            command.Connection = connection;
            connection.Open();
            
            // Execute the DataReader and access the data.
        OdbcDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            string txt = reader["TextFile"].ToString();
            TextBox textBox1 = ((TextBox)FormView1.FindControl("TextBox1"));
            textBox1.Text = " ";
          //  txtnewt = "~/Text/RishtonHistory.txt";
         // string txtout=System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name ;
          // string txtn = "\" " + txt + "\"";
            **string txtout = File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath(txt));**  
            textBox1.Text = txtout;

        }

        // Call Close when done reading.
        reader.Close();
        }
        
    }
}
```

the highlighted line is where the fault occurs.

I am using server 2019 in a virtualbox machine with aspx v4.7 and iis manager 10

I do not have aspnet as a user to add permissions
the line commented out for get name = IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool
To the best of my knowledge permissions are granted, so am unsure if this is a permissions issue. As I said it all works if I enter the path manually.

Comment: What is the error it is giving you?

Comment: Server Error in '/' Application.
Access to the path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\WebBuilder' is denied.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\WebBuilder' is denied.

Comment: Is the `.txt` on your local machine or a network machine?

Comment: the .txt is on the virtual machine in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\WebBuilder\Text\RishtonHistory.txt